# Woocommerce-Get Value of Custom Field in Checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, checkout, orders

I have a nimble question that i am not getting any answer of. I have added a custom field using "Checkout Field Editor" in Woocommerce Checkout fields. The field is given below and seems to be working fine.

```
 <input class="input-text " name="wc_order_field_7542" id="wc_order_field_7542" placeholder="Pickup Date" value="" type="text">
```

However, now I am working on a plugin and want to get value inputted in this specific field and cannot seem to figure out. For the other fields I am simply doing the following as I am doing for "billing email" and it is working:

```
public function get_billing_email() {
        $billing_email = $this->order->billing_email;
        return apply_filters( 'xc_woo_cloud_print_billing_email', $billing_email, $this );
    }
public function billing_email() {
    echo $this->get_billing_email();
}
```

I am sure I am forgetting something and not doing something right.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a custom field in your plugin, as `$this->order` seems to be the instance of the `WC_Order` object, you will try to use `$this->order->get_id()` to get the order ID.

Now you can try something using WordPress `get_post_meta()` to get your custom field value, this way:

```
$pickup_date = get_post_meta( $this->order->get_id(), 'wc_order_field_7542', true );`
```

> But check in `wp_postmeta` database table for the `meta_key` `'wc_order_field_7542'` that should exist for your orders. If it's not the case, you will have to find out the correct `meta_key` that is handling the **pickup date** data...